# How to fix recursive rule invocation in Antlr3?

Tags: antlr, antlr3, xtext

I have the following XText grammar which uses ANTLR3 under the hood. In my grammar I want to support cast expressions like `TYPE(EXPRESSION)` and `(TYPE)(EXPRESSION)`. A Type definition usually contains other types (I think that is the problem but I cannot change this requirement). Besides that I also want to allow parenthesis around expressions.

Is it possible to solve the recursion by left-factoring? I always get the following error message.

> [fatal] rule ruleExpression has non-LL(*) decision due to recursive rule invocations reachable from alts 1,2.  Resolve by left-factoring or using syntactic predicates or using backtrack=true option.

```
Model:
    e=Expression;

Expression:
    e=castExpression | e=parExpression | "VAR";

castExpression:
    (Type | '(' Type ')') e=parExpression;

parExpression:
    '(' Expression ')';

Type:
    "MYTYPE" t=Type | "TYPE_ID";
```

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski it's XText, which uses ANTLR3 under the hood

Answer (score 0):

The simplest but not neccessarily the best way to make it work is to put in a syntactic predicate (=>) on the whole castExpression like this:

```
Expression:
   =>e=castExpression | e=parExpression | "VAR";
```

But it seems like this is a very reduced excerpt of the actual grammar, so I cannot say if it is a viable solution in the full context. Also note that putting in such a long lookahead can have a bad effect on tooling aspects and performance. And you should be sure to understand the implications of syntactic predicates before adding more of them.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but is it possible to describe my grammar without syntactic predicates? I want to have an expression grammar with a "cast operators" like type(expression). The key problem is that I want to allow brackets around expressions _and_ types (because types can be complicated). I want to allow expressions like (type)(expr) or (type)((expr) + (expr)).